# Docker and Github Actions - "docker not found""

Tags: docker, dockerfile, github-actions

I'm trying to setup CI/CD for my Next.js app -> Docker -> private VPS.
I want to use the GitHub container registry.

For some reason, when trying to build to arm64, I'm getting an error "docker not found".

workflow file:

```
    name: Build and Deploy
    on:
      push:
        branches: [main]
      workflow_dispatch:
        inputs:
          logLevel:
            description: 'Log level'
            required: true
            default: 'warning'
    
    jobs:
      build:
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
        container: node:16
    
        steps:
          - name: Set up Docker Buildx
            uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2
          - name: Publish to Registry
            uses: elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action@v5
            with:
              name: user/lorem/ipsum
              registry: ghcr.io
              username: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
              password: ${{ secrets. GITHUB_TOKEN }}
              platforms: linux/amd64,linux/arm64
              #buildargs: NEXT_PUBLIC_BACKEND_URL,NEXT_PUBLIC_META_API_KEY
              tags: latest
      deploy:
        needs: build
        runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    
        steps:
          - name: Deploy package to Github Container Registry
            uses: appleboy/ssh-action@master
            env:
              GITHUB_USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
              GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
            with:
              host: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_HOST }}
              port: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_PORT }}
              username: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_USER }}
              key: ${{ secrets.DEPLOY_KEY }}
              envs: GITHUB_USERNAME, GITHUB_TOKEN
              script: |
                docker login ghcr.io -u $GITHUB_USERNAME -p $GITHUB_TOKEN
                docker pull ghcr.io/user/lorem/ipsum:latest
                docker stop app_prod
                docker system prune -f
                docker run --name app_prod -dit -p 3000:3000 ghcr.io/user/lorem/ipsum:latest
```

And Dockerfile

```
FROM node:20-alpine AS deps

#https://github.com/nodejs/docker-node/tree/b4117f9333da4138b03a546ec926ef50a31506c3#nodealpine
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache libc6-compat && apk add git

WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci

# Rebuild the source code only when needed
FROM node:20-alpine AS builder
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
COPY --from=deps /app/node_modules ./node_modules
ARG NODE_ENV=production
RUN echo ${NODE_ENV}
RUN npx prisma generate
RUN npm run build

FROM node:20-alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
RUN addgroup -g 1001 -S nodejs
RUN adduser -S nextjs -u 1001

#copy next config js if not using default config
COPY --from=builder /app/next.config.js ./next.config.js
COPY --from=builder /app/public ./public
COPY --from=builder /app/package.json ./package.json

COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=builder --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/.next/static ./.next/static

COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs prisma ./prisma/
COPY --chown=nextjs:nodejs bootstrap.sh ./

RUN apk add --no-cache ca-certificates openssl

RUN apk add --no-cache --upgrade bash
RUN ["chmod", "+x", "./entrypoint.sh"]
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]

USER nextjs
EXPOSE 3000
ENV PORT 3000
CMD ["./bootstrap.sh"]
```

In the *build* step, the action is throwing:
 `/__w/_actions/elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action/v5/entrypoint.sh: 32: /__w/_actions/elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action/v5/entrypoint.sh: docker: not found`

I need to build an image for arm64, due to the VPS configuration. I am not sure how I could include docker in here - do I have to modify my Dockerfile and install docker in there?
I've seen I could mount the docker.sock when running locally, but not sure how to approach this in the action.

EDIT:
bootstrap.sh is used for prisma migrations, so they work properly.

```
#!/bin/sh
# Run migrations
DATABASE_URL="file:./dev.db" npx prisma migrate deploy
# start app
DATABASE_URL="file:./dev.db" node server.js
```

Comment: On `deploy` or `build`? Isn't `elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action` in your `build` job?

Comment: @Azeem my bad - I edited the original question. It throws it in the "build" step.

Comment: Remove `container: node:16` and it should work fine. The steps for `build` job are running inside that container. See [`jobs.<job_id>.container`](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idcontainer) for more details on this.

Comment: I see. I filed an issue on the action, and got this response:
https://github.com/elgohr/Publish-Docker-Github-Action/issues/187

Also, yep - I figured I forgot the checkout step by now :)

Comment: Yes, that error should be resolved by removing `container: node:16`. Did you try it?

Comment: Yep - works as expected by removing container, and addign the QEMU step as mentioned. Thanks!

While I'm here - i heard it's not the best idea to use :latest, but to set-up some kind of tagging. Would you mind shedding some light for me on that?

Comment: And hm. It looks like docker is trying to run my bootstrap.sh file using node.

/app/bootstrap.sh:2
# Run migrations
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Node.js v20.9.0

Comment: Good. Please see [Publishing Docker images](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/publishing-packages/publishing-docker-images).

Comment: Regarding "**SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token Node.js v20.9.0**", is it in your `build` or `deploy` job now?

Comment: The job gets successfully executed. It's printed when the container runs.

Comment: Most probably, a syntax error in `server.js`.

Comment: It seems like it's running my "bootstrap.sh" file using NodeJS.

Comment: You have a script i.e. `./bootstrap.sh` in `CMD` in your Dockerfile. Is that intentional? Does your `entrypoint.sh` script expect `bootstrap.sh` as an argument?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255968/discussion-between-matic-and-azeem).